Can't turn on Bluetooth after force-stopping Bluetooth system app on OnePlus
I forced stop my OnePlus Nord CE 2 Lite's Bluetooth system (`com.android.bluetooth.oplus.overlay).

I can't turn on my Bluetooth button now.

And the button remains disabled even after rebooting your phone?
